# How to switch screen with mouse without borders?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

I have used mouse without borders successfully to control several pcs.

But I don't know how to switch screen : it is possible with some hotkeys according to this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fQuwtduvwGA but I can't see anywhere what hotkey it is.

Update: hello, I'm talking about viewing screen from computer 1 ON computer 2 a bit like remote desktop not about moving the mouse to the other computer. The video shows it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

> You can configure ShareMouse to switch monitors only if you hold the
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd> or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key. While moving the mouse cursor near the monitor
>   border.

Reported in: [ShareMouse](http://share-mouse.com/beta.htm).

Comment: hello, I'm talking about viewing screen from computer 1 ON computer 2 a bit like remote desktop. The video shows it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need http://synergy-foss.org/

Will work across multiple machines and operating systems

Comment: need to buy license :P